# What to do about [install] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Some ideas:

- Rename the [install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/install) tag, to something like [installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installation)?
- If applicable, get rid of it in favor of [package-management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-management) or something more specific ([apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt) or [yum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yum))?
- If not, limit it to OS installation and installations not involving a package manager?

Answer (score 10):

How about replacing it with [system-installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-installation), to distinguish it from already-existing [software-installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-installation)?

Answer (score 4):

Given the lack of opposition, I've declared [install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/install) a tag to be removed in the tag wiki. We can wear it off a little at a time.

It would be good to ban [install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/install), as well.