# Please blacklist the /install tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, blacklist-request

We've [long held](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/486/what-to-do-about-install-tag) that the [install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/install) tag is bad and should be split into [system-installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-installation) and [software-installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-installation).

There are over 200 instances that need to be disambiguated manually, so we're doing this mostly organically and it takes forever. Granted, it could go quicker if we set our collective minds to it, but we don't want to fill the front page with that so we'd keep doing a handful at a time.

Unfortunately, the questions keep coming in. I try to catch them early but some always fall through the cracks.

Please blacklist [install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/install) so that we can clean up the remaining occurrences. The tag wiki and excerpt for [install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/install) clearly states what tags to use instead.

Comment: Add there [tag:installation] to be in the safe side ;)

Comment: @Braiam No one's using it, so we don't need it blacklisted. The problem with [tag:install] is that as long as it exists, people keep using it on new questions.

Comment: Should probably consider [tag:installer] as well.

Comment: @derobert Why? What's wrong with that tag? It's definitely meaningful. Is it being misused?

Comment: @Gilles it seems to be mostly used as a synonym of either [tag:system-installation] or [tag:software-installation]. Either that, or it needs to be tagged a specific installer instead (as, e.g., anaconda experience doesn't help with debian-installer, other than to the extent its actually system-installation experience) [note I'e been retagging them... so there are less synonym uses now]

Comment: @derobert I know we have posts about designing or customizing installers, but they may be a small minority. This warrants a separate meta thread.

Comment: @Gilles Well, for all the of the 16 questions left, I think I'm just going to retag them if needed. Will see then if there is anything left to ask on meta. So few I guess it really doesn't need to be blacklisted anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I went ahead and *installed* this in the blacklist today.

.... *ducks*