# Tag to use for `/usr/bin/install`

Tags: discussion, tags, useless-tags

The `install` tag has the description:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG. Use /software-installation or /system-installation instead.

If this tag should not be used AT ALL, should its questions (63 of them) be retagged and the tag deleted? (I'd be willing to help if rep allows)

Which tag should I use for questions about `/usr/bin/install`?

Wouldn't it be better to clean out the `install` tag for non-`/usr/bin/install` questions, and update the tag to be:

> ONLY for questions related to `/usr/bin/install`. Use /software-installation or /system-installation otherwise.

Related: [Please blacklist the /install tag](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2532/please-blacklist-the-install-tag)

Comment: Seems reasonable but I’m afraid it’ll get re-abused.

Comment: [tag:gnu-install] is probably over-specific (there are other /usr/bin/install commands), but it is at least short and unambiguous...

Comment: @Kevin this works for me, with the explanation text as you mention.